# How to display success message once inserted successfully

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I jus want to show success message in my template page after submission of form. I jus redirected to the same page.

xxx.html

```
 {% if messages %}
     {{ messages }}
 {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('report'),{'messages':'hai'})
```

I didn't get anything. am getting the error like **Noreversematch** keyword arguments not found.

```
 Traceback Error:
   Reverse for 'report' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

in urls.py

```
  url(r'^(?P<name>[\w\d_\.\-]+)/reports-issue$', IssueMailSent.as_view(), name='report')
```

Comment: Please don't say what the error is "like" - put the traceback in the question so we can use the information in it to debug your issue. Superficially it looks as though you aren't giving an identifiable URL to `reverse()`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You are trying reverse a url like `/<name>/reports-issue` but you have not said what `name` should be.

Comment: <name> is not an issue. It passed dynamically

Comment: Looking at the code above, `<name>` is an issue - `reverse('report')` will fail, because it expects a `name` argument which you haven't included.

Answer (score 0):

When you `HttpResponseRedirect`, you are telling the user's browser to redirect to an new url. You cannot include a context, so it is not possible to include the message this way.

The easiest way to show a success message is to use Django's built in messages framework. You create the message, then redirect.

```
messages.success(request, "hai")
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('report'))
```

Please see the [messages docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/) for full instructions.

Comment: I tried like as you said. But it displayed always when loading the page. I jus want to display only after submission of form

Comment: The above code should only display the message once. If you create the message after the form has been submitted, then it will only be shown when the form is submitted. Without seeing your code, I can't tell what you are doing wrong.